# cant find out how to read a row from room database

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am new to Android studio, especially in room database.
I can't find out how to read a row from room database

```java
//in dao
@Query("SELECT * from qarindosh_table LIMIT 1")
Qarindosh getAnyQarindosh();
```

I couldn't find out how to read a row. Please help.
Room database is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM qarindosh_table")

List<ModelClass> getAllItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to read 1 specific row from a database. In order to do that, you need to query by primary key, usually named `id` in the Entity. Something like that:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM qarindosh_table WHERE id=(:id)")
Qarindosh loadQarindoshById(int id);
```